"Could not find driver" error with SQL Server on WSL 2 with Ubuntu 24.04
I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect my Laravel application to a SQL Server database. I'm running this setup on WSL 2 with Ubuntu 24.04, PHP 8.3.11, and Laravel Sail. Here’s a detailed overview of the problem and what I've done so far:

Installed Microsoft ODBC Driver for Ubuntu: I followed the official instructions to install the ODBC driver for SQL Server.

Installed the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv Extensions: I installed these extensions using the official Microsoft documentation for PHP with FPM.

Reviewed Laravel's config/database.php: I ensured the configurations for the SQL Server connection were correct and matched the expected parameters.

Updated the .env File: I modified the .env file to specify the SQL Server connection parameters.


Despite all the above steps, when I try to run my Laravel application, I receive the could not find driver error message when trying to log in.
Additional Information

I can successfully connect to the SQL Server database using DBeaver, which indicates that the database is accessible and allows remote connections.
I have verified that the extensions sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv are installed correctly, and I checked that they are listed when running php -m. Each one of the extensions has it's own .ini file, but I've also added the lines extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so and extension=sqlsrv.so into my php.ini file to ensure that the extensions would be automatically loaded anyway.

So, with that all being said, what could be causing Laravel to not recognize the pdo_sqlsrv driver despite it being installed? Are there any additional configurations or troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this issue?

There are frequently separate config files for the web server (presumably FPM in your case) and the CLI, I'll wager you've got the module enabled for just the CLI. Run phpinfo() from a page that gets rendered by the web server to see if the module is enabled there, and what ini file(s) it's reading. You might also verify that the *.so files are chmod go+r.

All of the examples in the second "Installing on Ubuntu with PHP-FPM" link you provided demonstrate installing the drivers for PHP 8.1. Did you make the appropriate edits to use 8.3 in all the places where 8.1 is used?

add your config/database.php and .env relating to the SQL driver you want to use.

Solution:
I was able to resolve the issue by installing the drivers directly inside the container where my application is running. Initially, I was trying to install the drivers in WSL 2 on my host machine, but since the application runs inside a container, the drivers need to be installed within that container’s environment.
Here’s a quick summary of the fix:

Access the container shell.
Install the drivers using the same steps from Microsoft’s official documentation.
Restart the container to ensure everything loads correctly.

After doing this, the error no longer occurs.

Bear in mind that if you install extensions in a container, the changes will be lost if you bounce the container. Do you have access to the Dockerfile that creates the image from which the container is derived?

Yes, I'm aware of that, but thank you for your advice anyway! Regarding the Dockerfile, I'm using Laravel sail to run my project. The file is automatically generated by Sail at the vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3 directory, which makes unfeasible for me to change it. I will consider working whitout Sail in the future because of this issue and use my own docker related files to run my project, but unfortunately I will have to keep it this way for now.

Ah righto, that makes sense. This problem appears to have been reported here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184992/how-does-one-add-php-extensions-to-the-docker-compose-yml-configuration-that-com

And also here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-install-add-php-extension-to-install-sail-on-existing-project

If the Docker image created by Sail is of a fixed name e.g. sail-local-php:latest, you can create a new Dockerfile starting with FROM sail-local-php:latest AND then do a one-line Ubuntu change in there. This will need to generate an image of a different name, so your start command will need to be able to accept the new image name.

Great to know! I will read those as soon as I can and try to aplly them into my project, specially that Dockerfile idea. Thanks a lot!
